# dplyr/dbplyr: sql table vs df speed

Tags: r, dplyr, r-dbi, dbplyr, monetdblite

I am currently writing a function with **dplyr** to do calculations. The function turns out to be really slow when I input a **tbl_sql** object, but reasonably fast when I input a **data.frame**.

An example,

```
df = data.frame(
  a = rnorm(1000000),
  b = rnorm(1000000),
  c = rep(1:5, 2000000),
  d = rep(1:10, 1000000)
)
library(dplyr)
library(MonetDBLite)
library(DBI)
mydb = dbConnect(MonetDBLite())
dbWriteTable(mydb, "df", df, overwrite = T)
dfdb = tbl(mydb, "df")

f = function(d, loc = F){
  d = d %>% mutate(i = a*b, ii = a/b)
  d2 = d %>% group_by(d) %>% summarise(sum(i)) %>% rename(k = d)
  d3 =  d %>% group_by(c) %>% summarise(sum(ii)) %>% rename(k = c)
  d4 = inner_join(d2, d3, by = "k")
  print(d4)
}
```

`system.time(f(df))` takes less than 1 second. **(data.frame)**

`system.time(f(dfdb))` it takes around 2 seconds. **(tbl_sql)**

My current function is longer and the inputted data is also larger, **(data.frame)** turns out to be more than 10 times faster than **(tbl_sql)** objects.

Why is that? Can anyone please explain.

Comment: it's likely that it's mainly the importation of data from the sql db that is taking time, or that the sql translation is inefficient (but i don't think it would be the case, see `?show_query`). How slow is it if you print `d3`(small object) instead ?

Comment: Probably because df is in memory, whereas dfdb is on disk.